# 3 level menu child link

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, multi-level

I have a simple code I saw in StackOverflow. This works great, but the problem I encounter is child links doesn't seem to work It doesn't go to the URL it is assigned to.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">

<li><a href="#">First Link</a>   
  <ul class="depth2">
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Go to Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Go to Yahoo</a></li>
  </ul> 
</li>

</ul>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
<script>
  (function($){ 
    $('.menu a').click(function( e ){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent('li').find('ul:first').slideToggle();    
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

I feel like a simple line of code is missing to make it work. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.preventDefault();` prevents the links from performing their default action, going to their assigned url.  That's why your links are working.  You can change you query to `'.menu > li > a'` to only select the top level of links.

```
<script>
    (function($){ 
    $('.menu > li > a').click(function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('li').find('ul:first').slideToggle();    
    });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried this before to no avail. I don't know why your code worked but yes this solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: The code you provided didn't work because your jQuery selector was selecting every link within the menu and preventing it from performing its default action.  The code I provided only selects the top level of links, allowing the other links to work as usual.  Does that make sense now?

Comment: Yes it does. I mean I tried using '>' in between the list before but it didn't work. I'm sure I missed some element or something. Thank you for the explanation.